# C function using structs, why is it not working?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I'm getting a host of errors with this implementation.

```
typedef struct EmployeeStruct
{
    char lastName[MAX_LENGTH];
    char firstName[MAX_LENGTH];
    int employeeNumber;  // Holds the employee's ID. This value is
                             // equal to the number of employees
    struct EmployeeStruct *Next;  // Pointer to the next most recently hired Employee
}Employee;
```

The problem comes when trying to create a function that will return a pointer to this struct. The error comes at the malloc call and leads to "new" not being declared correctly and therefore there are errors on all of the lines in this function.

```
Employee* hireEmployee(Employee tail, char lastName[MAX_LENGTH], char firstName[MAX_LENGTH])
{
    struct Employee *new = (Employee*)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
    new.lastName = lastName;
    new.firstName = firstName;
    new.next = tail;
    tail.next = new;
    new.employeeNumber = employeeCount;

    return tail;
}
```

Here is a list of the errors. Thanks for the help!

```
lab6.c:19: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
lab6.c:20: error: request for member ‘lastName’ in something not a structure or union
lab6.c:21: error: request for member ‘firstName’ in something not a structure or union
lab6.c:22: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
lab6.c:23: error: ‘Employee’ has no member named ‘next’
lab6.c:24: error: request for member ‘employeeNumber’ in something not a structure or union
lab6.c:26: error: incompatible types in return
```

Comment: Even if you write in C, using some popular C++ keywords like `new` is a little bit confusing.

Comment: ah, true. didn't even think of that. good point thank you

Comment: You are using `next` but defined `Next`. You don't declare `employeeCount`. You are not dereferencing your pointers: use `new->Next` instead us `new.next`. For starters. Oh - and you need to return the address (since your function has type `Employee*`), not the structure itself. `return &tail;`

Comment: employee count is a global variable so initialized earlier. fixed the next problem that was silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few different issues here:

You need to use the pointer dereference operator `->` to access members of a pointer to your struct.

You then need to use [strcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to assign to your `char` arrays.

You need to avoid a loop in your linked list (you were setting `new` and `tail` to point to each other as `next`).  The obvious fix would be to set `new` to be the new `tail`.  Calling code may need to be updated to reflect this.

Finally, you shouldn't cast the return from `malloc`

Really finally, `next` should be `Next`.  Or you could change the case in the struct definition.

```
Employee *new = malloc(sizeof(Employee));
strcpy(new->lastName, lastName);
strcpy(new->firstName, firstName);
new->Next = NULL;
tail->Next = new;
new->employeeNumber = employeeCount;
```

Comment: I am getting this error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

Comment: Which line gives you that error?  Are you compiling your code, my suggestions or something else?  Note also that I've updated my answer to fix another issue with the code.

Comment: Yea I changed name in the struc definition, silly mistake of me. But using your code for dereferencing pointers I get errors. Specifically, every line where it is used in the function. Thoughts?

Comment: p.s., there is no `struct Employee` type... just `Employee`.

Comment: @JeffMercado that certainly solved that problem. I think I'm going to take it from here and work the rest out, you guys have given me enough. Much thanks for getting me over that hurdle, gonna have to study up on pointers now....

Answer (score 0):

There are several things here.
1) Employee is already typedef, so no need to use struct in malloc statement.
2) new is a pointer to struct. So, way of accessing objects of struct through pointer is either StructPointer->StructObject or *(StructPointer).StructObject
3) I see you are trying to assign tail to next but passing tail as struct object. it has to be a StructPointer.
4) You should use strcpy to copy character arrays.